# Execute stored procedure by using batch file

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, sqlcmd

I wanna pass two parameters and execute stored procedure by using batch file.

If possible, I need something like below:

Please enter Param1:
Please enter Param2:

I have codes as below in my batch but is not working.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /P Param1=Enter the Param1: 
SET /P Param2=Enter the Param2: 
ECHO sqlcmd -E -Q "USE localdb\SQLSERVER2014 -d DemoDatabase;EXEC sp_MasterConsolidateJob @param1=N'%Param1%', @Param2=N'%Param2%'"
SET Param1=
SET Param2=

pause
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: In your sqlcmd, you have put your param1 and param2 inside double quotes(" "). Ideally, sqlcmd double quotes should be appended with params rather than inside quote.

Comment: Do you have any sample for it? Where should i place param1 and param2?

As below?

ECHO sqlcmd -E -Q "USE localdb\SQLSERVER2014 -d DemoDatabase;EXEC sp_MasterConsolidateJob" @param1=N'%Param1%', @Param2=N'%Param2%'

Comment: added solution. check and mark if it is useful. I tested it on my machine with similar sp. it works

Answer (score 0):

there is syntax issue in your provided code. We dont specify instance name. Run this, it should work :

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /P Param1=Enter the Param1: 
SET /P Param2=Enter the Param2: 
sqlcmd -E -Q " -d DemoDatabase;EXEC sp_MasterConsolidateJob $(Param1), $(Param2)"
SET Param1=
SET Param2=

pause
```

Comment: I get this error:

HResult 0x2, Level 16, State 1
Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : A network-related or in
stance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server
. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and i
f SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see
 SQL Server Books Online..
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : Login timeout expired.

Comment: This is totally trial and error based. Try to run the original query but with parameters as defined by me ie $()